# control a href link in wordpress to check the date and do one of two things

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am looking to control a link(href) using wordpress so that when it is pressed the site will do one of two things. 1- show a pop up window with a video embedded OR 2-check the date and if the link corresponds to a date in the future i.e. you click on the the 22nd and its the 21st (advent callender) the show a pop up image "you must wait until 22nd" else if the date has arrived then show the pop up video (option 1).
I program in java and have limited js

Comment: What have you done? Please share your code, we wont do it for you but will help if you have done something ...

Answer (score 0):

```
try this :

<div id="redemption">
    <a href="#" id="r1">Redeem</a>
    <a href="#" id="r2">Redeem</a>
   <a href="#" id="r3">Redeem</a>
 </div>
```

You can do like jfriend00 mentioned above:

```
$("#redemption a").click(function() {
var id = this.id;
```

// Assign the id to a custom attribute called data-id
   $("#printing_div").attr("data-id", id);

return false;
    });
     And then of course you can retrieve the new attribute in any AJAX call you
          send back to the server by:

var id = $("#printing_div").attr("data-id");
    Hope that helps.